# POWERBEATS PRO will not pair - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Nothing mentioned prior will work. I simply want my **Powerbeats Pro** headphones to work with my laptop...

Any *other* ideas than that which was already mentioned? 'cuz nothing suggested is working.

Is this an issue with Ubuntu/Linux in general or am I not doing something right?

(I don't want to go about installing a bunch of packages if I don't have to because I'm back on a fresh install after screwing up my sys doing that already). If I can't use these with Ubuntu then that's fine. I just would like to.

Comment: here is an article to help you -   https://www.nielsvandermolen.com/bluetooth-headphones-ubuntu/

Comment: Okay...yeah..going back to Windows 10 because at least this works on there without that BS...

On a side note, I do appreciate the help and I did mark this as adding something useful. I just don't think I should do that much terminal work just to get headphones working in Linux. Stuff like this should work...like, just work.

Comment: So, updating to 20.04 solved the issue. I guess they have updated drivers in this LTS release. Thank you for your help, though!